# SVM Vector-Distance Kernel: Valid? Experience?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I'm considering using the following simple function as an SVM kernel. It basically computes the distance between the 2 input vectors (norm):

**K(X1, X2) = || X1 - X2 ||**,   where **X1** and **X2** are N-dimensional vectors.

I'm not familiar with documentation of such a kernel.

Is is valid? Anyone experienced with such a kernel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just looked up that kernels have to satisfy the Cauchy Schwarz Inequality:

```
|k(x1,x2)|^2 <= k(x1,x1) * k(x2,x2)
```

Euclidean distance doesn't satisfy this, so I don't think it's a valid kernel for SVMs.

Comment: Where would I find a brief to-the-point list of all conditions that must be satisfied by a function for it to qualify as an SVM kernel?

Comment: @Yan Raf: I thought I read such a list some time ago, but I can't remember where. I've found this condition in "Learning with Kernels" in the chapter on kernels. Best open a new question for the necessary and sufficient conditions of an SVM kernel. And I think you might get better answers to that on stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Why doesn't Euclidean distance satisfy the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality?

Comment: @lars: If you replace `k(x1,x2)` with `||x1-x2||`, you get: `||x1-x2||^2 <= ||x1-x1|| * ||x2-x2||`. The right side is always zero.

Answer (score 1):

This is a distance, ie smaller is better. A kernel is a similarity function, ie larger is better. `1-(||x1-x2||/maxdist)` might be a kernel if you can define maxdist (eg by normalizing x1 and x2)